# Get all comments from comments table with user from user table and user image from morphed table?

Tags: laravel

I have three models : 'Post', 'User', 'Comment', 'Image'. The models 'Comment' and 'Image' has polymorphic relationship'
Now I want to get all comments of a post with with commenter user images. Can anyone help me how to solve it? My english is not good so if need clarification please do not hesitate to ask me

Comment: Try with hasManyThrough relationship https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have the following models and relationships:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->mophMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        // I assume that the comments table has a user_id field.
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

Then you can get the post with all nested relationship by saying:

```php
return $post->load('comments.author.image');
```